# Problems in sorting a column by value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to sort the food from the most caloric to the less caloric, I have a 2-column dataset (with about 2000 different foods), with the Name of the food and the Energy in kcal of that food.

| Name | Energy, kcal |
| --- | --- |
| Fish | 80 |
| Meat | 70 |
| Oil | 900 |

I tried with:

```
df_Kcal.sort_values(by='Energy, kcal',ascending=False).head(10)
```

But as a result, i have a list of foods from 99kcal (The highest value it's 900kcal)

| Name | Energy, kcal |
| --- | --- |
| Stockfish | 99 |
| Wine | 96 |
| lobster | 93 |

If I do the same code, with .sample(10) I can see foods with more calories around the dataset

How can I sort it correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Try `df_Kcal.sort_values(by='Energy, kcal',ascending=False)`

Comment: Hello Dark_Phoenix 
I have the same result

Comment: That is not what the question is about @Dark_Phoenix

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that this code doesn't sort values higher than 99; In my dataset there are calories values way higher than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kcal values seem to be stored as string, which explains the result of sort (values are sorted alphabetically).

To fix this, use [`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) to set the type of the kcal column to a numeric type (eg. `int`):

```
df.astype({'Name': 'string', 'Energy, kcal': 'int32'})
```

The sorting should then yield the expected result.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have some NaN in my dataset that I'm trying to drop, but my kernel dies every time. 
As soon as I'll fix that I'll let you know if I succeeded

Comment: Thank you very much! I cleaned the dataset, used your code, and it worked!